# Filter Observables before subscribing angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-observables

I have data like the one below in my mongoDB and I retrieve calling the service and later subscribing to it. But I want to filter the before subcribing to it in a way that i just subscribe to the filtered data base on my condition.
I want to filtered verifying that one of the camps in the data from the backend matches the "this.idcalbuscador". (See the .filter()). I haven't been able to achieve this, could anyone help? Just new to observables

Data

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("588850b746f8ce140c1fe8cf"),
    "idpertenalcalendario" : ObjectId("5885bfe452c6ba1d50f37f19"),
    "enabled" : true,
    "forma" : "Rombo",
    "color" : "Red",
    "type" : "point",
    "descrip" : "ghghghgh",
    "startDate" : "2017-01-15",
    "nameHito" : "gjgjgjgg",
}
```

Code

```
//retrieve the datas  

this._hitoService.getHitos()
    .filter(resp => resp.idpertenalcalendario === this.idcalbuscador )
    .subscribe(hito1 =>{
        if (typeof this.nom_cal1 === "undefined"){
            swal("Atencion!", "Busca un calendario con el buscador del Side Menu")
        }else {
            drawtimeline1_1(this.hito1, this.nom_cal1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What's going wrong then?

Comment: @ PierreDuc I couldn't see any data retrieved loaded into the page... it was all blank and there were no errors.

Comment: Can you also post the `this._hitoService.getHitos()` implementation? And it seems like you are doing nothing with the `hito1` variable inside the subscribe.

Comment: does subscribe works fine when filter is removed ?

Comment: @Priyamal Yes it works fine!

Comment: @PierreDuc Yes I can, and did see the datas saved in the DB.

Answer (score 2):

The `filter` function is not called for every item in your array, like it is for instance in Java's stream API. It is called for a single emittance of the Observable. That means the `resp` you work with in the filter function contains the array and *not* a single `hito`. That's why the following comparison will always return false:

```
resp.idpertenalcalendario === this.idcalbuscador
```

This is, at least, what I'd expect according to the names: `getHitos` returns an array of `Hito`. But Pierre Duc is right, it depends on your actual implementation.